# Deploying Google Cloud Functions ResponseError: The updateMask field contains event_trigger but it is not present in CloudFunction resource

Tags: node.js, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-functions, gcloud

I just started getting an error when trying to deploy a google cloud HTTP function using:

```
gcloud functions deploy http_function --trigger-http
```

And now I'm getting an error like this:

```
ERROR: (gcloud.functions.deploy) ResponseError: status=[400], code=[Bad Request], message=[The request has errors
Problems:
The updateMask field contains event_trigger but it is not present in CloudFunction resource.
]
```

The function deployed fine earlier and I've only fiddled with the some code inside, nothing that I believe should give me this error.

My cloud function looks like this:

```
exports.http_function = (req, res) => {
    if (req.method === 'POST') {
        // some code and then
        res.json(jsonVariable);
    } else {
        const error = new Error('Only POST requests are accepted');
        error.code = 405;
        console.error(error);
        res.status(error.code || 500).send(error);
        throw error;
    }
}
```

If anyone has some insight as to what might cause this error, I'd greatly appreciate it, because I'm struggling to find info on it?

**EDIT:** It only seems to happen sometimes, so now I definitely believe it's something wrong with gcloud.

Comment: Does it continue to occur? The error should only arise if you inadvertently try to update an existing HTTP triggered function using a command for a different Function type. This is unlikely if you're repeating the same command that you show.  Am I correct to assume that you're developing locally and then running that command? When it fails, do you try again and it then succeeds? I'm compelled to confirm that you're using the latest version of `gcloud`? You may wish to try appending `--log-http` to the command to capture the underlying HTTP requests (and possibly errors).

Comment: It occurs often, currently I can't get it working a single time. Yes I'm developing locally and am using the latest version of gcloud. I think you're right, deleting the function from cloud console and then redeploying does the job, but even then, after the first successful deploy, the next deploy (exact same function) gives the same error.

Comment: Same error with one of my Cloud Function I used to deploy from local code successfully before today. 2 other functions (same code, diverging only by the function name) on the same GCP project are deploying well using the same gcloud command. gcloud version is 215.0.0 and `--log-http` only reveal that `PATCH` request failed with `"code": 400, "status": "INVALID_ARGUMENT","details": [{"@type":"type.googleapis.com/google.rpc.BadRequest", "fieldViolations": [{"field": "updateMask", "description": "The updateMask field contains event_trigger but it is not present in CloudFunction resource."}]}]`

Comment: For reference, an [issue is opened](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/114661272) on the public issue tracker

Comment: Thanks for the follow-up and the issue tracker bug. I'm going to follow-up with some folks internally.

Comment: OK. This is a bug. It was caused by a recent update. A rollback is now underway that should address the issue.

Comment: And TIL: rerunning `gcloud functions deploy...` *without* specifying `--source` does *not* redeploy code. You must specify source to dedeploy locally changed files: "If the source location is not explicitly set, new functions will deploy from the current directory. Existing functions keep their old source."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error has been fixed now, see:
https://status.cloud.google.com/incident/cloud-functions/18002

"The issue with Google Cloud Functions experiencing errors when updating functions via gcloud has been resolved for all affected users as of Tuesday, 2018-09-11 09:10 US/Pacific. We will conduct an internal investigation of this issue and make appropriate improvements to our systems to help prevent or minimize future recurrence."

Answer (score 0):

I get the same when i try to deploy a pubsub triggered func, the error occurs on every other try. I just re-execute the CLI command and then it works.